# Could not initialize class in GXT GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am getting the below exception while executing my application. Here, I have created a class abcTextArea which extends TextArea and it has additional properties for a text box. But I am getting below exception. Can you please help me?

```
05:16:57,606 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/abcHtml]] (http-/10.1.3.22:8080-1) Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.abc.client.ui.abcTextArea
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
```

Comment: Can you show the code, please ...

Comment: You should not be instantiating this class in server code

Answer (score 0):

The class is not in your class path at runtime. http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html